# Can't print value from array TWIG

Tags: arrays, symfony, multidimensional-array, twig

I have a data array from the Instagram API. I have found out how to get the low_resolution value to print the images on the page. But for some reason I cannot get the caption value.

Below you can see my TWIG code. The image link is fine but why can't I get the text? The error i get from symfony is:

Impossible to access an attribute ("text") on a null variable in default/geogram.html.twig at line 23

```html
{% for value in images_array %}
<article class="col-md-3">
  <img src="{{ value.images.low_resolution.url }}" alt="" class="thumbnail img-responsive" />                 
  <p>{{ value.caption.text }}</p>
</article>
{% endfor %}
```

Below is the first index of the data being brought in from Instagram.

```html
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [attribution] => 
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => style
                    [1] => fashion
                    [2] => millinery
                    [3] => simonandmary
                    [4] => cvp
                    [5] => lfw
                    [6] => doghousestudios
                    [7] => lfw15
                    [8] => londonfashionweek
                    [9] => charleyvanpurpz
                    [10] => hat
                )

            [location] => Array
                (
                    [latitude] => 51.5122299
                    [name] => BFC Show Space, Brewer Street Car Park, London
                    [longitude] => -0.13417
                    [id] => 1014693484
                )

            [comments] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 0
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [filter] => Normal
            [created_time] => 1443003740
            [link] => https://instagram.com/p/7-DcwVrY3J/
            [likes] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 0
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [images] => Array
                (
                    [low_resolution] => Array
                        (
                            [url] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/11881754_1044165445613821_1998401000_n.jpg
                            [width] => 320
                            [height] => 320
                        )

                    [thumbnail] => Array
                        (
                            [url] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xpf1/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c6.0.1068.1068/10809626_1642110999378208_443887411_n.jpg
                            [width] => 150
                            [height] => 150
                        )

                    [standard_resolution] => Array
                        (
                            [url] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/11881754_1044165445613821_1998401000_n.jpg
                            [width] => 640
                            [height] => 640
                        )

                )

            [users_in_photo] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [position] => Array
                                (
                                    [y] => 0.98366013
                                    [x] => 0.078125
                                )

                            [user] => Array
                                (
                                    [username] => brad_hobbs
                                    [profile_picture] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/11849014_1659972384225731_1340681672_a.jpg
                                    [id] => 1376238
                                    [full_name] => Brad Hobbs
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [position] => Array
                                (
                                    [y] => 0.98366013
                                    [x] => 0.934640519
                                )

                            [user] => Array
                                (
                                    [username] => doghousestudios
                                    [profile_picture] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-19/10731472_1576813469216190_1504144557_a.jpg
                                    [id] => 1544718516
                                    [full_name] => Doghouse Studios
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [position] => Array
                                (
                                    [y] => 0.128686798
                                    [x] => 0.6046875
                                )

                            [user] => Array
                                (
                                    [username] => simonandmary
                                    [profile_picture] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfp1/t51.2885-19/10954789_372599292911615_195833317_a.jpg
                                    [id] => 309223601
                                    [full_name] => Simon and Mary
                                )

                        )

                )

            [caption] => Array
                (
                    [created_time] => 1443003740
                    [text] => In My Fav Felt Dip Dyed Monza By @simonandmary My Fav Hat Brand Right About Now Thanks To @doghousestudios For The Introduction ☺️. : @brad_hobbs . Day4 #LFW #londonfashionweek #LFW15 #Fashion #Style #CVP #CharleyVanPurpz #Hat #SimonandMary #doghousestudios #millinery
                    [from] => Array
                        (
                            [username] => charleyvanpurpz
                            [profile_picture] => https://igcdn-photos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/11311163_951968284859623_331958112_a.jpg
                            [id] => 54462914
                            [full_name] => Charley Purpz
                        )

                    [id] => 1080316135090261762
                )

            [type] => image
            [id] => 1080316130803682761_54462914
            [user] => Array
                (
                    [username] => charleyvanpurpz
                    [profile_picture] => https://igcdn-photos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/11311163_951968284859623_331958112_a.jpg
                    [id] => 54462914
                    [full_name] => Charley Purpz
                )

        )
```

Comment: try [`dump(value)`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html) to see what data you really have.

Comment: in my loop i have the following when i dump(value)

  "caption" => array:4 [▼
    "created_time" => "1443002488"
    "text" => """
      Два часа и неизвестное количество кружек кофе
      Хасл. Только сотка на столе"""
    "from" => array:4 [▶]
    "id" => "1080309186974028776"
  ]

Comment: there is a value for caption.

Comment: So is there a caption for every value (for every iteration)?

Comment: no there is not, i tried an if statement and still error persists

Comment: {% if value.caption.text %}
        <p>{{ value.caption.text }}</p>
             {% endif %}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess not every `value` inside the iteration has a `caption`. If so, try:

```
{% if value.caption is defined %}
  <p>{{ value.caption.text }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

or if necessary (e.g. `caption` could be defined without `text`):

```
{% if value.caption is defined and value.caption.text is defined %}
  <p>{{ value.caption.text }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

reference: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/defined.html

Comment: I am sorry that still does not work. 

"Impossible to access an attribute ("text") on a null variable in default/geogram.html.twig at line 24"